# Couldn't boot pre-installed system from HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I took the hard drive out, put it on an another PC and installed windows 7.
At the same time, I took all the other parts from the old pc, cleaned, and also reset BIOS.

After the installation finished, I remove the Hard disk and installed back on my old pc and booted it.
But the problem is now that Boot manager doesn't recognize the windows 7 which i installed earlier. How can I solve this problem? May anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/289330/3463

Answer (score 0):

If the machines are not identical, then (in most cases) this just won't work due to core hardware differences.

To solve your particular problem (re)install Windows on the actual machine you want to use it on.

For more information see the SU question [Removing HD from PC and putting in another PC](https://superuser.com/questions/289323/removing-hd-from-pc-and-putting-in-another-pc) (as Randolph West pointed out in his comment).